# my first app as a page tab, 'like' status is empty after user likes the page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I just learned how to create my first app as a welcom tab. Using directions here, http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/ I set up an if statement to check the signed_request 'like' status to determine which page to show. It worked perfectly the first couple of times but after I went to the test pages settings and set the welcome-test tab as the default landing tab, now the page still defaults to the wall tab but when I click on the welcom-test tab it shows me the non-fan content even though the like button is gone as it should be since I already liked it. I tested the like status again and it is empty as if I haven't liked it yet.

Can anyone tell me if this is a facebook bug or a problem in my code?

```
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];


//debug
echo "<br>page id = $page_id";
echo "<br>page admin = $page_admin";
echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
echo "<br>country = $country";
echo "<br>locale = $locale";

//everything comes back good here but like is empty

if ($like_status) {
echo "You like us";
}
else {
echo "<br/>You don't like us yet";
}

if($page_id == "245842635426802" && $like_status)
{
    include('pages/245842635426802.php');
}
else
{
    include('pages/245842635426802_nolike.php');
}
```

The page is here. https://www.facebook.com/pages/Testcompany/245842635426802?sk=app_377848798909813

Thanks

edit: I just checked the page and it worked once but then wouldn't work any more. I would think it was a network issue if it didn't return all the other values correctly. So I think it's a facebook bug just like when I add a like button to a web page and the count is always screwy.

I hate to keep adding edits but here's some more information.

I used another non admin fb user to test  and it worked several times and then all of a sudden, the same thing. No like button because I already liked the page but this time the entire getSignedRequest returns empty. So, something is going on with getSignedRequest only working part time. Anyone have any information on a problem with getSignedRequest only working some of the time?

Thank you

Comment: I checked your page and it works as intended

Comment: Can you show how you get the signed request?

Comment: Thanks Alexander Nenkov,

Comment: Ok I was having trouble with stack overflow. What I was saying is, I used the php code from here. http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/  It is working now for regular users so I guess it was just a matter of waiting for the fb servers to update. As for the admin user I still see the non-fan content but am going to replace that so admin sees a edit page to edit the content like other welcome tab apps do. Thanks for checking it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was a combination of waiting for fb servers to update, and checking the app while logged in as the apps admin. Even when using the dropdown to 'use facebook as' me rather than 'test-company', it still see's me as test-company so it shows the non-fan content but because i'm logged in as 'me' it has no 'like' button because 'me' already liked it.

So the answer in this case is, don't test while logged in as the admin of the page, and when using a fake user account for testing, wait a few hours for all the fb servers to update.

Answer (score -1):

```
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];


//debug
echo "<br>page id = $page_id";
echo "<br>page admin = $page_admin";
echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
echo "<br>country = $country";
echo "<br>locale = $locale";

//everything comes back good here but like is empty

if ($like_status) {
echo "You like us";
}
else {
echo "<br/>You don't like us yet";
}

if($page_id == "245842635426802" && $like_status)
{
    include('pages/245842635426802.php');
}
else
{
    include('pages/245842635426802_nolike.php');
}
```